# What kind of hard drive can I upgrade my laptop with?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, upgrade

Laptop: Dell Inspiron B130

Current HD: Toshiba 60GB ATA-6

I would like to upgrade to a hard drive with a lot more space; at least 120GBs. What kinds are compatible with my laptop? Is there a maximum size that it can handle? Any other recommendations for upgrading my HD?

Comment: From the Dell support forums: [What kind of Hard drive do I need for my Inspiron B130 Lap top upgrade? Confused Newbee](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19278952.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search has revealed [this 160GB one](http://www.lambda-tek.com/componentshop/index.pl?origin=gbase20.6&prodID=B96227).

> Origin Storage 160GB INSPIRON 1300 2.5IN 5400RPM MAIN/1ST EIDE HD KIT IN

It's a UK site.

Answer (score 1):

Western Digital still makes a number of PATA drives that should suit and most resellers should be able to obtain Wide range of sizes available

CDW US has the 160GB at $64.99

http://www.westerndigital.com/en/products/products.asp?DriveID=599